# anonymize rdbms datas, keeping key relations

Tags: dataset, rdbms, anonymize

Is there a "ready-to-use" method to anonymize datas, but keeping relations between keys ?
For example, I have :

- Table #1

| user code | zip code |
| --- | --- |
| ztxp15 | 45789 |

And :

- Table #2

| user code | order date |
| --- | --- |
| ztxp15 | 2021-06-27 06:22pm |

I want it anonymized as :

| user code | zip code |
| --- | --- |
| xvdf65 | 32165 |

And :

- Table #2

| user code | order date |
| --- | --- |
| xvdf65 | 2021-06-27 06:22pm |

This would need : a bijective function that transform a data, keeping its format ([a-z]{4}[0-9]{2}), generating the same value, according a passphrase for example.
In this way, unicity will be kept, format too, etc. But maybe I miss something.
I think that this problematic is very common so I am looking for previous work about it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common practice to use a user identifier, which my itself has no meaning to a viewer. I assume in your case this is the `user code`.

You should only anonymise PII (Personally Identifiable Information). You can encrypt it for bi-directionality, or hash it for single direction anonymise. Hashing is usually done when exporting data to analytics dashboards.

It is not a common practice to anonymise `user code`. If all PII is anonymised, then the `user code` is effectively anonymised.